# python parse and get more input from line

Tags: python

I need to parse a text file and get output and add them to list.

```
    with open(qwer.txt, 'r') as my_file:
        a = my_file.readlines()
        for line in a:
            for part in line.split():
                if "color=" in part:
                    p1 = part.split('=')[1] 
                    print(p1)
                    list1 = []  
                    p1.append(list1)
```

so, i have a line where i have two/more "color=" on same line and i need output to get both the colors:

> my color=red and my color=green

my desired output is:

```
red
green
```

and i need to add them to a list seperately as ['red','green'] .please help! answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can of course, use regex:

```
import re
str = "my color=red and my color=green"
p = r'color=([a-z]+)'
x = re.findall(p, str)
```

Comment: i need to add to list,how should i do it?

Comment: @adarshram The variable `x` __WILL__ be a list. You can read about [`re.findall()` here](http://devdocs.io/python/library/re#re.findall)

Comment: how should i open my files and perform this operation rath?er than a single str

Comment: @adarshram After `for line in a:`, use `line` instead of `str`

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is almost correct, you print the correct lines. Here is how to save them to a list:

```
result = []
with open('qwer.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        for part in line.strip().split():
            if "color=" in part:
                p1 = part.split('=')[1] 
                result.append(p1)
```

If you need a list of lists, do it like this:

```
result = []
with open('qwer.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        values = []
        for part in line.strip().split():
            if "color=" in part:
                p1 = part.split('=')[1] 
                values.append(p1)
        if values:
            result.append(values)
```

Comment: I'd do `line.strip().split()` , I doubt if he wants "red\n" in his list.

Comment: Indeed, added the `.strip()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can do it without regex:

```
parts = itertools.chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in my_file)
colors = [part.split('color=')[1] for part in parts if part.startswith('color=')]
```

Although regex do seem to fit here best.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably we should avoid using groups. You could get the value of color through lookbehind,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = 'my color=red and my color=green'
>>> m = re.findall('(?<=color=)\S+', str)
>>> m
['red', 'green']
```